# How to pass information from one form to another form of viewModel on button click in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button

I have two form in wpf form1 and form2.

In form1, I have two radiobutton with one button control.
On button click event following operation is happening:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    form2 md = new form2();
    md.Show();
    this.Close();
}
```

and form2 code is like this:

```
 private MainWindowViewModel mainWindowViewModel;

 public form2()
 {
       InitializeComponent();
       this.mainWindowViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel(this);
       base.DataContext = this.mainWindowViewModel;
  }
```

MainviewModel which contains all the logic for data display related.

My question is this:

User can select any radio button from given option and after that he will press OK button. 
If user will select radio button1, so I want to take content of radiobutton and it will go to form2 and that go to mainviewModel class which can replace the following code:

```
em = EmFact.CreateEm(Protocol.Pro1, 2);
```

So In place of Protocol.Pro1, It should take radiobutton content.

Answer (score 1):

I havent been dealing with WPF for a long time now, but as far as I can see you have the ability to modify the constructor of the form ? So why not pass the information as parameters. You are creating an instance of the form when showing it in your event, thus you can pass it in the constructor there.

Sorry if that doesnt help

Answer (score 0):

If I am right in assuming you have a two models which you want to pass data between?

Install MvvmLight from Nuget. It includes a Messaging namespace which provides you with a way of sending objects as messages. You register in your view model constructor a way of handling this data, which of course, can be to update properties.

have a look [at JesseLiberty.com](http://jesseliberty.com/2011/01/06/windows-phone-from-scratch%E2%80%93mvvm-light-toolkit-soup-to-nuts-3/) for a walkthrough.

Basic example would be a login scenario:

Our login view model would send a message:

```
MessageBroker.Messenger.Send<LoginSuccessMessage>(new LoginSuccessMessage() { UserName = "user" });
```

In this case we pass a LoginSuccessMessage object which just has a username property...
Then in another view model, we register a handler:

```
this.MessengerInstance.Register<LoginSuccessMessage>(this, this.OnLoginSuccessMessage);

private async void OnLoginSuccessMessage(LoginSuccessMessage message)
    {
        this.CurrentUserName = message.UserName;
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Form1 is simple selection window only, No corresponding viewmodel and for Form2 I have ViewModel and Model. I hope I'm clear now with my question.

Comment: Fortunately the Messenger is available as a singleton, so you can use that in your form code behind in the same way you might in the first view model. Similarly, you could register to message receive events in the code behind of your form2. You just need to fully qualify it...
GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging.Messenger.Default.Send<T>(T)
GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging.Messenger.Default.Register<T>(...)